# A problem on square bricks.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

Assume $n$ square bricks with sides $1,2,3,...,n$ where sides of them are parallel to $x,y-$ axis. They are arranged in a pattern in which each brick touches exactly $2$ bricks and two bricks touches such that they have only a vertex common. Prove that $\forall n\geq5$ such arrangement exists?

So, for this problem I tried proving by induction. It's not a big deal to prove such an arrangement willn't possible for $n=1,2,3,4$. So induction follows as,

I've made structure of $n=5$ which is like this,[image]

Now, I'm unable to get a general conversion from $n=5$ to $n=6$ i.e. $n=i$ to $n=i+1$. Is there a conversion? And what will be the other methods to prove the arrangement to be exist only if $n\geq5$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I need general conversion to complete my solution. But I asked for other approaches to solve the problem.

Comment: @DietrichBurde my bad. I edited the question.

Comment: (-1) APMO problems are to be kept confidential until they are posted on the official APMO website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *almost* a proof without words, so I'll let the image speak for itself. What you do with it is up to you.

[image]

Comment: [+1] Nice ! [Connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3266470/305862)

Answer (score 0):

For any value $n$, we can search for a pattern like this :
[image: octogone]

A,B,C,D are mandatory.
Each group $E_i, F_i, G_i, H_i$ may be empty, or contain 1 or many squares.

So we have to solve :

$\Sigma h_i + d + \Sigma g_i = \Sigma e_i + b + \Sigma f_i$

$\Sigma h_i + a + \Sigma e_i = \Sigma g_i + c + \Sigma f_i$

Probably, the parity of $\frac{n(n+1)}2$ will have an impact at any step.